# Is it safe to force shutdown when on grub screen?

Tags: grub2, shutdown

The title says it all.

My computer has been restarting instead of shutting down. A possible workaround is to force shutdown pressing the power button. Is it safe?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Absolutely no problem.

There are virtually no operations current on your hard disk (if any!), so there aren't any files on your hard disk that will be messed up by having the computer shut down suddenly.  In fact, shutting down the computer with the power button is the [recommended method](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1341990) on Ubuntu forums (when the computer is in grub).